# Does the starting index affect the convergence/divergence of two equal-term series?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

Say I have a convergent series $\sum_{m}^∞ a_i$. Does $\sum_{n}^∞ a_i$ converge when $m>n$? Similarly, does it converge when $m<n$?

Comment: First, what does "$\sum_n^\infty a_n$" mean?  I have no idea how $n$ varies from $n$ to wherever.  Is $a_i$ defined for $i \in [\min\{m,n\}, \max\{m,n\}]$?

Comment: You need a "dummy index" to sum over, not something that has a meaning outside of the sum, so I think you mean $\sum_{k=n}^\infty a_k$, not $\sum_n^\infty a_n$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael yes. sorry for the ambiguity.

Comment: @EricTowers m,n takes on natural numbers and $a_i$ is defined on the said interval.

Comment: @EricTowers okay I edited my question now. Did I get the meaning across? I'm sorry I'm not used to formal definitions as I'm only an undergrad student who is currently taking Calc II.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convergence or divergence is unchanged, since the difference between the series is a finite sum of finite terms, so it is finite.

I am assuming that each $a_i$ is finite.